# How find all commits which modified custom file or date interval? GIT

Tags: git, git-commit

I have deleted my local branch without pushing about 3 months ago, I do not know how to find it, but I know that there should be a commit which modifies x.cs file. How can I find all commits which touch that file or date interval?

Comment: Your "date interval" addition does not make sense to me. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean can I find all commits in certain date interval for example 01.05.2020 - 02-05-2020

Answer (score 0):

Deleted branches are not tracked by git (branches are only refs to a commit)

But there are good news. Unreferenced commits will keep living for a while, so (maybe) you could find these commits in the reflog. Try this:

```
git log --all --graph --oneline --reflog
```